# Django - Relate to a user group a new record of another model

Tags: python, django

I want that when creating a new record in another model, it automatically relates to each of the users in another model.

Example: I have a 3 models:
  - Events
  - Participants
  - Users

When adding a new event you must add all users to the list of participants.

I know I can do it with a cycle but I want to know if there is another way in django something like for example

```
'''model Participants ''' 

Class participants(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

''' view '''
    event = Events.objects.get (id = instance.id)
    participants = Participants (event = event, user = User.objects.all ())
    participants.save ()
```

Comment: django `signal` will do it. why calling a field `id_user` while it just contains the users list Instance? why calling a field `id_event` whereas it contains the instance of model which has already the id automatically created by django?

Comment: @Lemayzeur  I'm sorry I should have included more information, but my question is not about calling signals, it's about whether I can add all the users without having to cycle, as in the example I did.

Comment: I don't get it sorry. what you really mean!

Comment: @Lemayzeur Ok let me explain myself better, I just want to know if django accepts
participants = Participants (event = event, user = User.objects.all ())
participants.save ()
to add all my users to the event

Comment: It would accept it if `user` was a `ManyToManyField()`

Answer (score 0):

Django provides the field `ManyToManyField` for that

```
Class participants(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User,blank=True)
    # It's suggested to use plural: users = ....
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In your view you would do:

```
event = Events.objects.get (id = instance.id)
participants = Participants (event = event)
participants.save()
participants.user.add(*User.objects.all())
```

You can’t associate it with a `User` until `participants` has been saved:
Don't forget the positional arguments * `*` before the queryset `*User.objects.all()`, if not Django will raise an error

or much better:

```
participants = Participants.object.create(event = Events.objects.get (id = instance.id))
participants.user.add(*User.objects.all())
```

If you want to know behind the scenes of how Django does [check this out](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#id1)